# meteor mongo find return mongo error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to do some really simple thing but having errors for some reason..

when i am trying to `collection.find({createdAt:somevalue})` it dosen't work, but if I am trying to `collection.findOne({createdAt:somevalue})` the document returns successfully.

[image]

p.s working with mongolab if it important to figure it out.
end goal is to use that query :

```
 Meteor.methods({
  'getChartData': function(startts, endts) {
    var chartRes = Logger.find({
      createdAt: {
        $gte: startts,
        $lt: endts
      }
    }, {
      _id: 0,
      rms: 1,
      status: 0,
      createdAt: 1
    });
    console.log(chartRes);
    return chartRes;
  }
});
```

I need to get all the documents (between timestamps, from the server side) and return them to client (with the rms & createdAt index's only).

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, i was needed to add .fetch() after the .find({}) like this:

```
collectionName.find({}).fetch()
```

:)